# How to fix the position of an image after moving it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch

I am using `- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`  to move an image.How I can fix its position  after moving it.I mean I would like when I choose the right position,the image should not move no more.

Comment: What have You tried? Show some code how You tried it. Anyways, I would  store a bool value for image - in case touches moved to some right side or above a different view, I would detect that, and change bool value - as image not movable any more. Then upon touches moved, I would check bool value, and return if that is true.

Answer (score 3):

Add PanGesture to the imageView containing the image.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
//method to move imageView whereever you want in the view,you can also write conditions to restrict the imageView not to go beyond bounds.
- (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint imageViewPosition = imageView.center;
    imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
    imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;


    imageView.center = imageViewPosition;

    [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];

//you can use if(panRecognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){} condition to fix the position of the imageView.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
{  
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];  
    UIImageView *view1 =moveImageView;  
    CGPoint point = [touch  locationInView:self.view]; 
    //the right position
    if(point.x==?&&point.y==?){

             rightPosition = YES;
             moveImageView.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 50, 50);
     }else{
            //the UIImageView you want to move 
            if(!rightPosition){
               moveImageView.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 50, 50);
          } 
    }
}
```